# Using the verb "erscheinen" just like in english

Tags: english-to-german

I would like to know,could I use "erscheinen" for "appear" like its english equivalent.

Context:
[image]

And my translation attempt:

In dem Satz '...', welche der folgenden erscheint nicht?

Comment: Ich denke ", welche oder welches der Folgenden erscheint nicht" ginge. (Die Konjunktion/Preposition, das Adverb/Adjektiv).

Comment: "Welche der folgenden Wortarten kommen in dem Satz '...' nicht vor?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though *erscheinen* is not really wrong here (i.e. you will be understood, and probably there are folks who would not even take notice), it seems more idiomatic to me to use *auftreten*. I would also recommend to not follow the original sentence structure 1:1, but rather rephrase it like e.g.

> Was tritt in dem Satz "..." nicht auf?
>   Welche Wortart tritt in "..." nicht auf?
>   Untersuchen Sie den Satz "...". Welche der folgenden Wortarten tritt darin nicht auf?

Two other alternatives would be *vorkommen* (thanks to [PerlDuck](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/22180/perlduck) for suggesting it) and *vertreten sein*, so e.g.

> ... Welche der folgenden Wortarten kommt darin nicht vor?
>   ... Welche der folgenden Wortarten ist darin nicht vertreten?

The verb *erscheinen* (in the meaning that does matter here) always comes with a sense of dynamic or change ("it wasn't there before, but now it is"), but here we are talking about something completely static.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist deine Antwort nicht richtig. Üblicherweise spricht man davon dass Wörter in Texten *vorkommen*. Google findet einhundertzweiundsechzig Milionen Belege für "wort kommt * vor". Man sagt normalerweise nicht, ein Wort würde *auftreten*. So findet Google nur neun Belege für "wort tritt * auf".

Comment: @what Mal abgesehen davon, dass ich nirgendwo davon schreibe, dass ein _Wort_ auftritt, sondern nur Wort*arten*, bezweifle ich, dass Dein Argument wirklich belastbar ist. Für die Plural-Variante "wörter treten * auf" kündigt mir Google nämlich knapp 2,5 Mill. Treffer an.

Comment: Der Bezug ist die Wahl (Einzahl), nicht die Arten (Mehrzahl) - daher "tritt" statt "treten".